# Not able to refer Foreign Key refer in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I having two table models, one is a parent and another is child

This is my parent model

```
class users_table(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users_table'
    userid = Column(String(50), unique= True, primary_key= True, nullable= False)
    username = Column(String(500), unique= True, nullable= False)
    password = Column(String(500), nullable= False)
    email = Column(String(500), nullable= False, unique= True)
    role = Column(String(10), default= 'user', nullable= False)
    created_on = Column(DateTime, nullable= False, default= datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    updated_on = Column(DateTime, nullable= False, default= datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    children = relationship("user_status_table")
```

This is my child model

```
class user_status_table(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user_status_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key= True, nullable= False, unique= True, autoincrement=True)
    userid = Column(String(50), ForeignKey('users_table.userid'), nullable= False, unique= True)
    status = Column(String(50), default= 'active', nullable= False)
    updated_on = Column(DateTime, nullable= False, default= datetime.datetime.utcnow)
```

When running my server its giving the following error:

```
"When initializing mapper Mapper|users_table|users_table, expression 'user_status_table' failed to locate a name (\"name 'user_status_table' is not defined\").
```

If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the  class after both dependent classes have been defined."

Answer (score 0):

As I see you are trying to establish one to one relation between users_table and user_status_table because you want user_status_table.userid to be unique, to achieve this use the **uselist** flag

Below is a simple example:

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    child = relationship("Child", uselist=False, back_populates="parent")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
    parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="child")
```